# Inserting data from 1st table to 2nd table in different locations

Tags: c#, database, ado.net

In foxpro, I can simply do this to add or merge table with different locations:

```
-> use C:\tableA
-> append from D:\tableB
```

in this foxpro code I've provided, `tableB` which exists from location `D:\` appends all its row into `tableA`.

The question now is, how do I do that in `C#`?

I can simply invoke this query: `insert into tableA select * from tableB` to append all rows from `tableB` to `tableA`. But this is only true when I used same database and their file location remained intact and same at the same time.

My problem is that the database location of these two tables were different. How do I resolve this problem using `C#`?

Comment: What is the database in question? SQL Server? Access? MySQL?

Comment: I'm using Foxpro OleDb in C# application.

Answer (score 0):

looking to linq statements. What kind of database is this? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/172b4f22-8c6e-4186-9ff4-e593fbda7566/can-i-use-linq-or-sqlstatements-to-transfer-values-from-one-table-to-another?forum=lightswitchgeneral